# To find minimum in the rows

Tags: python, set

While process the csv file - rows and columns - we need to find the minimal value from ALL the rows, I try to make a set from each row and then find the minimal value in each row. I don't know if it is right, maybe there other way. In the output we obtain the column of minimal values, I need only one minimal value from all

Input like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIAQR.png)
I need only one value:    10

The code:

```
import csv
with open('input_3.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')

    d = set()
    k = list()
    for row in range(1):
        next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        a = row[1:]
        d=min(a)
        print(d)
```

Output:

```
54
67
14
10
```

Comment: `min(min(row[1:]) for row in reader)`

Comment: Yes, this is really effective))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
min(row[0] for row in reader)
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jeremy! I will keep this in mind for my future responses.

Answer (score 0):

@Anna, 
     Are you just trying to find the minimal or smallest value in your csv ? You could do something like this:

```py
   import pandas as pd 

   df = pd.read_csv(file_path) 

   # To get smallest value in each column 
   smallest_value_by_column = df.min(axis=0) 

   # To get smallest value in each row
   smallest_value_by_column = df.min(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps. First is find min for each row. Then min around it.

```
import csv

with open('input_3.csv') as File:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter=';')

    min_rows = []
    for row in reader:
        value = min(row)
        min_rows.append(value)

    print(min(min_rows))
```

Comment: Thank you, it's great!